# i have been trying to make my website responsive but the image is being weird

Tags: html, css

when I implemented the responsive CSS for different sized monitors the button when to the right space, but the image that is supposed to be on the button just sits in a random spot. I want the image to stick to the button no matter the way the page responds to screen size

HTML:

```
<button id="popout-button" onclick="popout()"><img id="popoutMenuImg" src="Images/lightmodeicon.png" alt="menu"></img></button>
```

CSS:

```
#popout-button {
  width: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please insert your code completely

Comment: what do you mean by that i pretty new to posting on here and to making websites

Comment: Welcome to SO, here is a look to help you structure your questions in a way that can help others reproduce the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.